# Dynamically updating values using selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a selection box that will update  multiple values dynamically using selection box. I found a few samples online but none of them seems to be doing exactly what I need.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/badatz/18ncvkur/1/

```js
function OnSelectionChange(select) {
  var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = selectedOption.id;
  document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = selectedOption.id2;
  document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML = selectedOption.id3;
  document.getElementById('p4').innerHTML = selectedOption.id4;
  document.getElementById('p5').innerHTML = selectedOption.id5;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="8">
  <tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td>Field 3</td>
    <td>Field 4</td>
    <td>Field 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="p1">Change me</td>
    <td id="p2">Change me</td>
    <td id="p3">Change me</td>
    <td id="p4">Change me</td>
    <td id="p5">Change me</td>
</table>
<br>
<div align="center">
  <select onchange='OnSelectionChange (this)'>
    <option id="G1" id2='Green' id3="Greg" id4="Boy" id5="GGG">Green</option>
    <option id="Y1" id2='Yellow' id3="Yolanda" id4="Girl" id5="YYY">Yellow</option>
    <option id="R1" id2='Red' id3="Rob" id4="Boy" id5="RRR">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a change to your fiddle to make it a little more ["DRY"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

I also noticed that your table is missing a closing `<tr>` tag.

Here's a snippet below to demonstrate.

```js
/**
 * Gets called when the change event gets fired on the select element.
 * 
 * @param {string=} ddwnId The identifier of the select element.
 */
function OnSelectionChange(ddwnId) {
  var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  var dataset = selectedOption.dataset;
  var pId = '';
  var attrId = '';
  /*
  On the select element above I have added an id attribute and set it
  to "id1". You could access that Id and use that in the switch statement
  below. The other option is just to pass the Id in as a parameter to our
  OnSelectionChange function.
  */
  var id = this.id;
  
  switch (ddwnId) {
    case "id1":
      alert(`Dropdown with id "${ddwnId}" triggered OnSelectionChange!`);
      break;
    default:
      //No case was found for that dropdown id.
      break;
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    pId = 'p' + i;
    attrId = 'id' + i;

    document.getElementById(pId).innerHTML = dataset[attrId];
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="8">
  <tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td>Field 3</td>
    <td>Field 4</td>
    <td>Field 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="p1">Change me</td>
    <td id="p2">Change me</td>
    <td id="p3">Change me</td>
    <td id="p4">Change me</td>
    <td id="p5">Change me</td>
  <!-- You were missing a closing tag here... -->
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div align="center">
  <select id="id1" onchange='OnSelectionChange.call(this, "id1")'>
    <option data-id1="G1" data-id2='Green' data-id3="Greg" data-id4="Boy" data-id5="GGG">Green</option>
    <option data-id1="Y1" data-id2='Yellow' data-id3="Yolanda" data-id4="Girl" data-id5="YYY">Yellow</option>
    <option data-id1="R1" data-id2='Red' data-id3="Rob" data-id4="Boy" data-id5="RRR">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and optimization, it's going to be very helpful for me as  I would be pulling data from an array so using the "for" loop is a great optimization.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add an id/name to the <select> so I can add an IF statement  in the function to know from which `<select>` box the function was called? 
`<select onchange='OnSelectionChange.call(this)'  id="box1">`

And in the function add something like:
`if id= "box1" ....`

Comment: @badatz There is a way. I will update the snippet to show a couple of ideas about how you can achieve this.

Comment: Works like charm, you are the king of Javascript!  thanks again

Answer (score 2):

When using *custom attributes* ([`data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)) you must ideally prefix it with `data-` and access it uisng `element.dataset.attributeName` - see [`updated fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/hbqoucu9/) and demo below:

```js
function OnSelectionChange(select) {
  var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex];

  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = selectedOption.id;
  document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = selectedOption.dataset.id2;
  document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML = selectedOption.dataset.id3;
  document.getElementById('p4').innerHTML = selectedOption.dataset.id4;
  document.getElementById('p5').innerHTML = selectedOption.dataset.id5;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellspacing="8">
  <tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td>Field 3</td>
    <td>Field 4</td>
    <td>Field 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="p1">Change me</td>
    <td id="p2">Change me</td>
    <td id="p3">Change me</td>
    <td id="p4">Change me</td>
    <td id="p5">Change me</td>
</table>
<br>
<div align="center">
  <select onchange='OnSelectionChange (this)'>
    <option id="G1" data-id2='Green' data-id3="Greg" data-id4="Boy" data-id5="GGG">Green</option>
    <option id="Y1" data-id2='Yellow' data-id3="Yolanda" data-id4="Girl" data-id5="YYY">Yellow</option>
    <option id="R1" data-id2='Red' data-id3="Rob" data-id4="Boy" data-id5="RRR">Red</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Darnit you beat me too it, dataset is the way to go for something with multiple attributes. if you're going to be using the dataset for everything wouldn't it make sense to make the first `id` also in the dataset?

Comment: @WayneO nope, because `id` is not a custom attribute, and it is not good practice...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Javascript does not know about id2, id3, id4, and id5. I am not exaclty sure what you are trying to do, but putting multiple values into id* attributes of an HTML tag does not look right to me.

You might want to work with objects, e.g.:

```
var persons = {
    G1: {
        name: "Greg",
        gender: "Boy",
        color: "Green",
        colorCode: "GGG"
    },
    Y1: {
        name: "Yolanda",
        gender: "Girl",
        color: "Yellow",
        colorCode: "YYY"
    },
    R1: {
        name: "Rob",
        gender: "Boy",
        color: "Red",
        colorCode: "RRR"
    }
};
```

Now you can use this object to read specific values into your table by referencing the keys inside the object.